# C#: IoT AWS v4 Signing Request

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to sign a request to be sent to AWS without success. After hours browsing online I couldn't find a piece of code that would work.

I want to pre-sign an IoT url in C#. I have found code in Node that is extremelly simple:

```
'use strict';

const v4 = require('aws-signature-v4');
const crypto = require('crypto');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const url = v4.createPresignedURL(
        'GET',
        process.env.IOT_ENDPOINT_HOST.toLowerCase(),
        '/mqtt',
        'iotdevicegateway',
        crypto.createHash('sha256').update('', 'utf8').digest('hex'),
        {
            'key': process.env.IOT_ACCESS_KEY,
            'secret': process.env.IOT_SECRET_KEY,
            'protocol': 'wss',
            'region': process.env.IOT_AWS_REGION,
        }
    );

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({ url: url }),
    };

    callback(null, response);
}
```

How would this be done in C#? I couldn't find it on the SDK. What I did find is this method: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Core/Amazon.Runtime/Internal/Auth/AWS4Signer.cs

But it says it is for internal use only and shouldn't be used.

Any guidance on how to achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [sample here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-dotnet) in the past with great success. You will need to slightly modify it to make it work for your use case.

Hope that helps!